# How to fetch the website name from localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I would like to fetch the website name from the localstorage. Generally we use localstorage.getItem(key) to get the value inside the localstorage. But I want the link name itself.

For Eg- from the image I want https://stackoverflow.com as my output.

[Local Storage Image Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0P92.png)

Comment: I'm not sure that the 'name,' (the URL) is available to JavaScript running in the browser from local storage; I *think* that's provided by the client in order to allow users to inspect the contents of their machine's storage and identify from which website that content originated. The only local storage contents a website can access is that which it set itself. So knowing the URL of the current page - as Hemant suggests - should meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks David for the info. I also tried to fetch using window.location.hostname but just out of curiosity i wanted to know whether I will be able to fetch from local storage.

Answer (score 2):

You can just get the name from the url using `window.location`. You can do this instead

```
var protocol = window.location.protocol
var hostname = window.location.hostname

var url = protocol+"//"+hostname
console.log(url)
```

Comment: Thanks Hemant, I also used window.location.hostname for fetching it. But I was just wondering is it possible to fetch from local storage. But as David mentioned it seems we wont be able to get the URL from local storage. Thanks again!